# Passing ID in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am working on an app, however I am stuck currently on how to approach this.

```
import React from "react"
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom"

import LandingPage from "./LandingPage/"
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard"
import CustomRoute from "../utils/CustomRoute"
import Pages from "./pages/Pages"
import PublicTrip from "./Maps/singleTripPublic"

const Root = () => (
  <Switch>
    <CustomRoute path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
    <CustomRoute path="/app" protectedPath component={Dashboard} />
    <CustomRoute
      path="/public/:tripId"
      render={({ match }) => <PublicTrip tripId={match.params.tripId} />}
    />
    <CustomRoute path="/" component={Pages} />
    <CustomRoute render={() => <div>404: Route not found</div>} />
    <Pages />
  </Switch>
)
export default Root
```

This is my root.js, I want to know how I can pass the tripId into Link tag so that it renders public/"tripId" when the link is clicked. If you scroll down you can see  tag with tripId. How do I pass in tripId so that it actually redirects to it when I click. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import React from "react"
import * as s from "./components"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import moment from "moment"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { TripPropTypes } from "../../propTypes"
import { Button } from "../../../styles/theme/styledComponents"
import { toggleWaypoint } from "../../../redux/actions/trips"
import marker from "../../icons/orange-marker.svg"
import startMarker from "../../icons/green-marker.svg"
import endMarker from "../../icons/black-marker.svg"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

class ActiveTripPanel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      polylines: null,
      markers: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.renderWaypoints()
      this.drawPolylines()
    }, 500)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.waypoints !== this.props.waypoints) {
      this.renderWaypoints()
      this.drawPolylines()
    }
  }

  drawPolylines = () => {
    if (this.state.polylines !== null) {
      this.state.polylines.active.setMap(null)
      this.state.polylines.complete.setMap(null)
      this.state.polylines.current.setMap(null)
    }

    let completeIndex = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.waypoints.length; i++) {
      if (!this.props.waypoints[i].complete) {
        completeIndex = i
        break
      }
    }

    const completed = this.props.waypoints.slice(0, completeIndex)
    const active = this.props.waypoints.slice(
      completeIndex,
      this.props.waypoints.length + 1
    )
    const current = this.props.waypoints.slice(
      completeIndex - 1,
      completeIndex + 2
    )
    const completePath = completed.map(waypoint => {
      return { lat: waypoint.lat, lng: waypoint.lon }
    })

    const activePath = active.map(waypoint => {
      return { lat: waypoint.lat, lng: waypoint.lon }
    })

    const currentPath = current.map(waypoint => {
      return { lat: waypoint.lat, lng: waypoint.lon }
    })
    const completePolyline = new window.google.maps.Polyline({
      path: completePath,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    })

    const currentPolyline = new window.google.maps.Polyline({
      path: currentPath,
      strokeColor: "#008000",
      stokeOpacity: 1.0,
      stokeWeight: 2
    })
    const activePolyline = new window.google.maps.Polyline({
      path: activePath,
      strokeColor: "#000000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    })

    completePolyline.setMap(window.map)
    activePolyline.setMap(window.map)
    currentPolyline.setMap(window.map)
    this.setState({
      polylines: {
        active: activePolyline,
        complete: completePolyline,
        current: currentPolyline
      }
    })
  }

  renderWaypoints = () => {
    let markers = []
    const baseIcon = {
      anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(15, 30),
      scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(30, 30),
      labelOrigin: new window.google.maps.Point(15, 13)
    }
    const icons = {
      start: {
        url: startMarker,
        ...baseIcon
      },
      end: {
        url: endMarker,
        ...baseIcon
      },
      marker: {
        url: marker,
        ...baseIcon
      }
    }
    this.props.waypoints.map((item, i) => {
      const icon =
        i === 0
          ? icons.start
          : i === this.props.waypoints.length - 1
          ? icons.end
          : icons.marker

      let center = { lat: item.lat, lng: item.lon }
      const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: window.map,
        icon,
        title: item.name,
        label: {
          text: `${i + 1}`,
          color: "white",
          fontFamily: "Wals",
          fontWeight: "bold"
        }
      })
      markers.push(marker)
    })
  }

  render() {
    const publicId = ({ match })
    return (
      <s.Panel>
        {/* <s.PanelHeader>{this.props.trip.name}</s.PanelHeader>
        <s.DateLabel>
          Start: {moment(this.props.trip.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD")} - End:{" "}
          {moment(this.props.trip.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
        </s.DateLabel> */}
        <Link to="/public/{match.params.tripId}">Share Trip</Link>
        <s.WaypointTracker>

          {this.props.waypoints &&
            this.props.waypoints.map(waypoint => (
              <s.WaypointStepper key={waypoint.id}>
                <div>
                  <h4>{waypoint.name}</h4>
                  <div>
                    ETA: {moment(waypoint.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    Status: Checked In @{" "}
                    {moment(waypoint.start).format("HH:mm")}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  {waypoint.complete ? (
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => this.props.toggleWaypoint(waypoint.id)}
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-check" />
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => this.props.toggleWaypoint(waypoint.id)}
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-times" />
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </div>
              </s.WaypointStepper>
            ))}
        </s.WaypointTracker>
      </s.Panel>
    )
  }
}

ActiveTripPanel.propTypes = {
  trip: TripPropTypes,
  waypoints: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  toggleWaypoint: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ trips }) => ({
  trip: trips.activeTrip,
  waypoints: trips.activeTrip && trips.activeTrip.waypoints
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { toggleWaypoint }
)(ActiveTripPanel)
```

[EDIT]

CustomRoute code

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router"

import { addTokenToState } from "../redux/actions/auth"

const CustomRoute = props => {
  const { isLoggedIn, protectedPath, checkedForToken, ...rest } = props

  // If not logged in and haven't checked for token yet,
  // try to query DB for user with token:
  if (!checkedForToken && !isLoggedIn) {
    props.addTokenToState()
  }

  if (isLoggedIn || !protectedPath) {
    return <Route {...rest} />
  }

  if (protectedPath && !isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: props.path }
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn,
  checkedForToken: state.auth.checkedForToken
})

const mapDispatchToProps = { addTokenToState }

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CustomRoute)
```

Comment: show your `CustomRoute` code

Comment: I have added the custom route code to the main question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
<Link to="/public/${match.params.tripId}">Share Trip</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this doesn't seem to help. It just changes my url to the following. ``` http://localhost:3000/app/trip/%60/public/$%7Bmatch.params.tripId%7D%60 ```

Comment: Are you getting the tripid ?? trying printing it console

Answer (score 0):

Change from this

```
<Link to="/public/{match.params.tripId}">Share Trip</Link>
```

To this

```
<Link to={`/public/${this.props.match.params.tripId}`}>Share Trip</Link>
```

**Update**

If you want to access `match` object in your Component you have to pass `match` like this

```
<CustomRoute
   path="/public/:tripId" 
   render={({ match }) => <PublicTrip match={match} />}
   // or this render={props => <PublicTrip {...props} />}
/>
```

in your code you just pass `tripId` so that mean you can't access `match` object, you can get `tripId` like this `this.props.tripId`

so your Link should be like this

```
<Link to={`/public/${this.props.tripId}`}>Share Trip</Link>
```

---

Actually you don't even to to use render to get match params, just simply as this

```
<CustomRoute path="/public/:tripId" component={PublicTrip} />
```

And `Route` will inject `match` to your `ActiveTripPanel`, so you can get match params in your `ActiveTripPanel` like this `this.props.match.params`

Comment: This doesn't seem to help either, thanks for the reply. Gives me a similar url to the other answer.

Comment: @UsmanJaved try log `tripId` this first  `console.log(this.props.match.params.tripId)` if you don't see id in console, check your `CustomRoute`

Comment: Hey Tried to console log but it gives me the following error "Cannot read property 'params' of undefined"